# Карта на сайт (Не google)

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго времени суток.
Делаю некое подобие карты и столкнулся с проблемой.

1. Масштабирование. *(!important)*
   Как реализовать "шаговое" масштабирование, к примеру как на гугл картах?
   Допустим скроллишь вниз, каждый шаг был +1.
2. "Координаты".
   Координаты начинаются с левой верхней части.
   А в игре, из которой взята карты, отсчёт идёт от центра.
   Как такое же, реализовать на сайте?
   Допустим:
   От центра влево (-10,0), от центра вправо (+10,0);
   От центра вверх (0,+10), от центра вниз (0,-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой Leaflet: http://leafletjs.com/

Там можно настроить кастомную карту.

Примеры реализации: http://leafletjs.com/examples.html

Comment: Увы не выйдет. Я взял карту из игры GTA San Andreas, она имеет 144 куска карты. В общем суть в том, что мне по сути то нужна возможность отдалить пару раз картинку и приблизить. А вот с координатами я уже почти разобрался.